# Django Templates not showing Views.py variables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a django project running on Linux server (via digitalocean)

The problem I am experiencing is peculiar, everything works, but the communication between the templates and the `views.py` file seems to not be working.

**for example :**

*the app name is 'gaapp'*

If I add `<h1>This heading is to test if changes to the templates are picked up</h1>`, in the `gaapp/templates/gaapp/dash.html` file, then it works successfully (I can see the heading on the site)

But if I add a variable `<h2>This {{variable}} should show on the site</h2>`, then nothing shows.

Any ideas?

**myprojectdir/gaapp/urls.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.dash, name='dash'),
    path("pages", views.pages, name='pages'),
    path('users/', views.users, name='users'),
]
```

**myprojectdir/gaapp/views.py:**

```
bunch of imports

def dash(request):
    variable = "This is the variable that should be displayed, as in the example"
    return render(request, 'gaapp/dash.html',
                  {"variable": variable})
```

EDITED:

I haven't touched the settings for templates..

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok. Make sure you have restarted your server so that it is using the latest version of the view and template.

Comment: It depends on your server setup. If you are using Gunicorn you can do it via a command like this. `sudo systemctl restart <name of youer gunicorn service>`.

Comment: The amount of gratitude I have.. This project will be presented on Friday and you really just help me so much! Thanx both Daniel and Alasdair. It worked !